# mysql order by with top four or three or two group rows based on input

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, greatest-n-per-group

> SELECT fname AS 'manager', lname AS 'DR'
>   FROM emps e
>   INNER JOIN emps m
>       ON m.empId = e.repTo
>   order BY  manager

Result of the above query is

```
 manager1    repor1
 manager1    repor2
 manager1    repor3
 manager2    repor4
 manager2    repor5
 manager3    repor6
 manager3    repor7
 manager3    repor8
 manager4    repor9
 manager4    repor1
```

How do I select the top two manager details, three manager details, or N number manager details?

Two manager details mean it should return like the following

```
 manager1    repor1
 manager1    repor2
 manager1    repor3
 manager2    repor4
 manager2    repor5
```

Comment: limit means it returned top 2 records

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Another stick with no lollipop. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: mysql version 5.5.21

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select m.fname AS manager, e.lname AS dr
from emps e 
inner join emps m on m.empId = e.repTo
where (select count(*) from emps e1 where e1.repTo = e.repTo and e1.lname <= e.lname) <= 2
order by manager
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It returns the top two records for each manager.

 manager1    repor1

 manager1    repor2

 manager2    repor4

 manager2    repor5

 manager3    repor6
 manager3    repor7
 manager4    repor9
 manager4    repor11

I want two manager details

Answer (score 0):

1.

````
```select * from table_name A where manager in
(select distinct TOP 2 manager from table_name B  order by manager Asc)```
````

2.

````
```select * from table_name A left join
(select distinct TOP 2 manager from table_name order by manager Asc) B on A.manager = B.manager```
````

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want for the ordering.  If the ids work, then:

```
SELECT fname AS manager, lname AS DR
FROM emps e INNER JOIN
     emps m
     ON m.empId = e.repTo 
WHERE e.manager <= (SELECT DISTINCT m2.repTo
                    FROM emps m
                    ORDER BY m2.repTo
                    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
                   );
```